# Calling extend_from_slice multiple times?

Tags: rust

I have a rust function where I append a bunch of slices together into a long vector.

The struct it takes looks like this:

```
pub struct PhyPayload {
    pub mtype: u8,
    pub nonce: [u8; 13],
    pub fcnt: u16, // Message Number
    pub devaddr : [u8;4],
    pub dh_pub_id: u16,
    pub ciphertext: Vec<u8>,
}
```

and it packs all the values of the struct together like this:

```
pub fn pack_payload(&self) -> Vec<u8> {
    let PhyPayload {
        mtype,
        nonce,
        fcnt,
        devaddr,
        dh_pub_id,
        ciphertext,
        
    } = self;

    let mut buffer = Vec::new();

    buffer.extend_from_slice(&mtype.to_be_bytes());
    buffer.extend_from_slice(nonce);
    buffer.extend_from_slice(devaddr);
    buffer.extend_from_slice(&fcnt.to_be_bytes());
    buffer.extend_from_slice(&dh_pub_id.to_be_bytes());
    buffer.extend_from_slice(ciphertext);

    buffer
}
```

But is there not a nicer way to do this exact thing? perhaps a function where I can map over all these elements and add them together?
So I don't have to have these calls next to each other?

Comment: If I'm being honest, this code is 100% readable as it is and additional abstraction to get the bytes from the fields would probably be a detriment unless you have good reason for it. Not everywhere you see repetition is actually a problem.

Comment: Also, if you're not adhering to some pre-existing message structure, this is pretty close to what [`bincode`](https://crates.io/crates/bincode) will do automatically.

Comment: hm, yeah okay, i guess it'l stay as is then

Comment: The only thing I might consider doing is computing the length of the message in advance, which appears to be just a single constant plus `ciphertext.len()`, so that you can tell `buffer` how much capacity it needs. This would avoid reallocations to grow the vector.

Comment: cool, that would just with ` Vec::with_capacity(n)` right?

Answer (score 1):

I would write it like this:

```rust
pub fn pack_payload(&self) -> Vec<u8> {
    let PhyPayload {
        mtype,
        nonce,
        fcnt,
        devaddr,
        dh_pub_id,
        ref ciphertext,
    } = *self;

    mtype
        .to_be_bytes()
        .into_iter()
        .chain(nonce)
        .chain(devaddr)
        .chain(fcnt.to_be_bytes())
        .chain(dh_pub_id.to_be_bytes())
        .chain(ciphertext.iter().copied())
        .collect()
}
```

This has the additional advantage that the iterator has the correct size hint, so unnecessary reallocations are avoided when collecting into a `Vec`.

Comment: Just curious why you went with `to_be_bytes` and not `to_le_bytes`?

Comment: I just reproduced the behavior of OP's code. I don't know what the code is supposed to do, so I didn't alter its behavior.

Comment: Ah I see I had missed it out.